# Script Variables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-scripts

Given two tables

```
USERS
UID NAME
1   KEN

ADRESS
AID UID CITY
1    1  LONDON
```

I'd like to have an Oracle SQL Developer script that outputs two result tables just like if I'd had entered two select statements one after another.

This does NOT work, I couldn't assign the u_id variable:

```
select UID into u_id from USERS where NAME='KEN';
select * from USERS where UID = u_id;
select * from ADRESS where UID = u_id;
```

The output should of course be

```
UID NAME
1   KEN

AID UID CITY
1    1  LONDON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this in SQL Developer.

With a bind variable:

```
variable u_id number

execute select U_ID into :u_id from USERS where U_NAME='KEN';

select * from USERS where U_ID = :u_id;
select * from ADRESS where U_ID = :u_id;
```

Or with a substitution variable:

```
column U_ID new_value sub_u_id;
set verify off

select U_ID from USERS where U_NAME='KEN';

select * from USERS where U_ID = &sub_u_id;
select * from ADRESS where U_ID = &sub_u_id;
```

Which in this case you could simplify to:

```
column U_ID new_value sub_u_id;
set verify off

select * from USERS where U_NAME='KEN';
select * from ADRESS where U_ID = &sub_u_id;
```

Read more about the [`variable` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm), the [`execute` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm), the [`column` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm) and it's [`new_value` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#sthref797), and [substitution variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB) in the SQL*Plus documentation - much of which applies to SQL Developer as well.

Demos with tables created with slightly different column names, to avoid key/reserved words:

```
create table USERS (U_ID number, U_NAME varchar2(10));
insert into users values (1, 'KEN');
create table ADRESS(A_ID number, U_ID number, CITY varchar2(10));
insert into adress values (1, 1, 'LONDON');

prompt Demo 1: bind variables

var u_id number
exec select U_ID into :u_id from USERS where U_NAME='KEN';
select * from USERS where U_ID = :u_id;
select * from ADRESS where U_ID = :u_id;

prompt Demo 2: substitution variables

column U_ID new_value sub_u_id;
set verify off
select * from USERS where U_NAME='KEN';
select * from ADRESS where U_ID = &sub_u_id;
```

Run as a script, the script output window shows:

```
Table USERS created.

1 row inserted.

Table ADRESS created.

1 row inserted.

Demo 1: bind variables

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

      U_ID U_NAME   
---------- ----------
         1 KEN       


      A_ID       U_ID CITY     
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 LONDON    

Demo 2: substitution variables

      U_ID U_NAME   
---------- ----------
         1 KEN       

      A_ID       U_ID CITY     
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 LONDON
```

You can suppress the `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed` message with `set feedback off`, of course.

Comment: Alex, thanks very much for your great answer. The bind variable example works perfect for me. The NEW_VALUE verb is marked as error by the Oracle SQL Developer SQL Worksheet editor, but the script still works.

Comment: Yes, it has a few syntax marking idiosyncracies. I should probably check the SD forum to see if they've been reported really *8-)